# After AJAX Receiving NoneType when passing data to SQLAlchemy in Heroku no issues in local

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, heroku, sqlalchemy

I make an ajax call to send data to python (using flask) to update my postgresql table with additional data. In my local machine there are no errors, however, when I deploy to Heroku I get:
**a 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name'.**
If I click the button a couple of time it goes through. How do I address this error?

I simplified the code to only contain one variable.
Here is the ajax call.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
       var first_name = $('#first_name').val()


       $.ajax({
           data : {
               first_name : first_name,

           },
           type : 'POST',
            url : '/process'
        })
        .done(function(data) {
               window.location.href = "/page2"
        });

        event.preventDefault();

     });

    });
```

Here is what I am trying to update in Python using SQLAlchemy.

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def page2_process():
    global app_id
    update = Data1.query.filter_by(id = app_id).first()
    update.first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
    db.session.commit()
    return json.dumps({'success': True}), 200, {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

I have tried:  request.form['first_name']  I still have the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Adding the log as requested:
The first line of the log is the log telling me that the update object is not empty. Because it has object 18 from Data1.

```
<Data1 18> 
[2017-10-26 06:58:25,886] ERROR in app: Exception on /page2_process [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1982, in wsgi_app
     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1517, in handle_user_exception
     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", 
line 33, in reraise
     raise value
    File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
     rv = self.dispatch_request()
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 
 1598, in dispatch_request
     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
   File "/app/app.py", line 396, in page2_process
     update.first_name = request.from.get('first_name')
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'first_name'
```

Comment: Make sure `request.get_data()` is not empty before you access the `first_name` attribute

Comment: This data is not empty in my local, and if I press submit multiple times in heroku it goes through, so I don't think it is empty. Also I am not sure what is meant by request.get_data(). Is that an alternative for request.form.get()?

Comment: I'd start checking from `update = Data1.query.filter_by(id = app_id).first()` and if it is actually returning `None`. And if you want help, provide the *full traceback*, not just the message of the exception object.

Comment: "/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
"/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
"/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
"/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
"/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
"/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
"/app/app.py", line 394, in page2_process
update.marital_status = str(request.json['marital_status'])
NoneType object is not subscriptable

Comment: Please edit tracebacks to your question, properly formatted. And that traceback is not the same you've referred to in your question originally.

Comment: @IljaEverilä added full log. Thank you.

Comment: The traceback is telling you that "Note: This is the log telling me that the update object is not empty." is false, or in other words `update` is None.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @IljaEverilä please see the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't control the client request in heroku change your ajax call like below:

```
  $.ajax({
         url: '/process',
         data: JSON.stringify({  'first_name ':first_name}, null, '\t'),
         type: "post",
         contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
         success: function(data){   
             window.location.href = "/page2"
         }
   });
```

And in Python you can access the attributes with `request.json`

```
@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def page2_process():
if request.json:
    global app_id
    first_name = str(request.json['first_name'])
    update = Data1.query.filter_by(id = app_id).first()
    if update:
        update.first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
    else:
        //insert
    db.session.commit()
return json.dumps({'success': True}), 200, 
                     {'ContentType':'application/json'}
```

Comment: did you check this answer? @Dave

Comment: I just ran that I am getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.@lalithkumar

Comment: what you are getting in the update object?it should not be empty?check my updated answer @Dave

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I have added some logs to see if the update object is empty; it is not, it has the data object. So I don't think it has to do with update. Again this works on local, just not on heroku. @lalithkumar